# How to remove hover effects from my WordPress website

Tags: css, wordpress

I cannot figure out how to remove the mouse over effects from both the logo and 'try apptive free' menu button on my website www.getapptive.com. What am I doing wrong?

www.learntosalsa.com/blog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'try apptive free' add following css:

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #1abc9c;
}
```

Comment: Add to the end of this file both answers

http://getapptive.com/wp-content/cache/minify/000000/bc5BCsAgDATAD7XVL0WJJaBJaELF39dLoVBvy84eNgZz4Iqj60yj4hY_TTYLScTNL9CjEf-0awLDJRVh36GjSVsPGpxMhfIEUHW68T3xAA.css

Comment: It didn't seem to work. I added it to the bootstrap.min.css file. I wan't 100% sure if that was the one you commented. If it isn't let me know and I will put the code in the correct style sheet.

Comment: Do you have cache enabled?
Alternatively you can use wordpress plugin to add custom css.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Comment: I opted for the plugin and it worked! Thank you. How could I get this to work without the plugin? I would rather add it to the proper css file rather than have another plugin.

Comment: Do use any caching plugins like W3 Total Cache, WP Fastest Cache, WP Super Cache?

Comment: Yes, I just installed W3 Total earlier today.

Comment: :) disable W3 Total Cache plugin,  make desired changes to your css file then activate W3 Total. And just to make thinks for sure, look in W3 Total option to recache (refresh) content.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

add following css:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
color: #1abc9c;
background-color: transparent; }
```

Comment: I added it to the style.css